# create levels for data frame column explicitly

Tags: r

Quite often, data frames are created based on some raw data and these "down stream" data frames' factor levels may not be aligned. Is the following, the correct way to created a level x, which may exist in another data frame with the same signature?

```
df <- data.frame(
    c1 = c("a", "a", "b", "c")
)

df
str(df)

df$c1 <- factor(as.character(df$c1), ordered = FALSE, levels = c("c", "a", "b", "x"))

df
str(df)
```

Comment: Sorry, what is your question ?

Comment: @RonakShah "Is the following, the correct way to created a level x, which may exist in another data frame with the same signature?"

Comment: Maybe I was not clear, I didn't ask to repeat the same thing. Try to explain it in a different way. I don't understand what do you want to show by doing `ordered = FALSE` and `ordered = TRUE`. Also `as.character` seems unnecessary when you have `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`. Remove it?